# Git auto merge commits from another repo

Tags: git, github, git-merge, githooks, cherry-pick

I have 2 private **repository** (not branches) `A` and `B` of which I have full access to.

Whenever `A` makes a commit, I want `B` to `cherry-pick` or `merge` the new commit into it (assuming no merge conflicts), so that `B` will always be up-to-date with the latest changes from `A`.

How do I accomplish this with Git hook or something else?

A shell script is less flexible as it means you have to commit/push with command line rather than GUI (eg. with [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)).

Comment: Do you want a mirror?

Comment: @F.V. repository `B` has some commits that `A` doesn't have. But I want all commits from `A` to automatically apply/merge to `B` if there's no conflict.

Comment: this is one of those things that one must ask _why_ would someone want to do this?  It seems likely this is a solution to a problematic problem.

Comment: @thekbb the manager requires me to maintain 2 websites (with different domains) with different themes for different clients (stupid, I know). I use Netlify for automatic deployment so the 2 versions must reside in different Github repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In repository `A` create a [post-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_commit) that switches to repo `B` and runs `git pull`.

The kind of "switching" depends on where `B` resides. If it's on the same computer the hook can just `cd /path/to/B`, but don't forget to clear `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` env vars before running `git pull`. If `B` is on another server the hook should `ssh` there.

Comment: A `post-receive-hook` is also a possibility.
Since there is development allowed on both repositories, where `B` is _not_ a mirror, merge conflicts are possible. You might want to catch those?

Comment: `post-receive-hook` — depends on how commits are added to `A`. *merge conflicts are possible* — the OP have said *assuming no merge conflicts* and I prefer to stop here. :-)

Comment: Git hook will not take effect if someone else pushes to the repo since it's locally hosted? Is there a way for it to work for commits made by others to the remote repo?

Comment: Is the only solution to host an API server and set up web hook on the remote repo?

Comment: [Server hooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) run when someone pushes to the repo.